# Need to format PHP Results in a query

Tags: php, sorting, filtering, limit

I am a Monkey see Monkey do Programmer. so at my age to old to learn anything new. I do need some advice and help!

I need to pull data from a table. (See table fields below)

- ID
- Title
- DatePosted
- Description
- Picture

(This i can do and list them perfectly below each other) using

```
<?php 
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
        $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");// Sets encoding UTF-8
        $sql = "select * from TableNews Order by DatePosted ASC LIMIT 5 " ;
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if($result !== false) {
            $cols = $result->columnCount();
            foreach($result as $row) {
                echo $row['Title'] . "\n";
                echo $row['DatePosted'] . "\n";
            } 
        }
        $conn = null;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

This works perfect !!!

Here is where i need advice.

In my results i need the first record that comes out to only list the title and the picture
anbd the remaining 4 Records only to show the -Title -DatePosted -Description.

Much of a Muchness like the news image included here

Thank you

[image: screen capture i took from Fox News]

Comment: Use a counter `$i` and increment it by one each loop. If it's equals `0` (or `1` depending if you start with 0 or 1 as initial value of your counter) print out the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
    $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");// Sets encoding UTF-8
    $sql = "select * from TableNews Order by DatePosted ASC LIMIT 5 " ;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if($result !== false) {
    $cols = $result->columnCount();
    $rowcount = 0;
    foreach($result as $row) {
    if ($rowcount==0) {
        echo $row['picture']."<br>";
        $rowcount++;
    } else {
        echo $row['Title']." - ".$row['DatePosted'];
    }
    if ($rowcount==4) {
        $rowcount=0;
    }    

    } 
    }
    $conn = null;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
```

Something like this where you set the counter initially to zero then increment it for each row to display when its hit your 4th row then reset the counter to zero so it'll repost the picture.  (this last stage is only required if you're planning on using multiple header images every 5th display otherwise you can remove the 2nd iff statement with $rowcount==4

Comment: Thank you Dave... It works Just the way i wanted it to.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample to help you figure out what you exactly need: (by the way you only have to use `<?php ?>` once if your code is only containing php)

```
<?php
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
    $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");// Sets encoding UTF-8
    $sql = "select * from TableNews Order by DatePosted ASC LIMIT 5 " ;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if($result !== false) {
        $cols = $result->columnCount();
        foreach($result as $key => $row) {
            if ($key === 0)
               $row['Picture'];
            echo $row['Title'];
            echo $row['DatePosted'];
        }
    }
    $conn = null;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```